# xcode - Progress bar under table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, progress-bar

i have some problem with my progress bar , its under table view 
my progress bar from class called MBProgressHUD

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

this pic of my error

[image]

Comment: @mohammad-- u got it working now?

Comment: its work but i need show my progress above my tableview

Comment: did you try my code? its working for me.

Comment: yes my code is    progressBar = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:progressBar];
    progressBar.labelText = @"Loading";
    progressBar.square = YES; but still have same problem

Comment: Update this
[[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view]; to 
[[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];

Comment: its still have same problem

Answer (score 4):

Use this while adding loader to your code.

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:hud];
hud.labelText = @"Loading...";
hud.square = YES;
[hud show:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Create and add Object of MBProgressHUD after creating tableView object...

As Last added object will come above all other untill you specify index of that element. In your case may be tableview is added after MBProgressHUD thats why its coming above the progress bar

Comment: It will work fine because last time I also have same problem. If we create MBProgressHUD  after tableview create then work fine ... try this

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy to use this library. You only need to call to

> showHUDAddedTo: animated:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
```

Check if you have after to show your MBProgressHUD object any call like

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView];
```